# how can I add command line parameters to an application shortcut

Tags: applications

Chromium has command line flags.  I'd like to use them, but I'd like to put them on the shortcut, since I tend to launch Chromium via spotlight.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an Automator app called "ChromiumLauncher" that runs the commands you want. Drawback is you will get the ChromiumLauncher bouncing in your Dock for a second or two before it goes away.

Comment: Automator!  Why do I keep forgetting about that thing?

Answer (score 12):

It will launch faster if you cut out Automator and just do it with Applescript (and then save that applescript as an application bundle).

Here's an example:

```
do shell script "open /Applications/Chromium.app --args --enable-expose-for-tabs"
```

Comment: +1 Good to know. Didn't know AppleScript could make Apps.